# Drupal 7 User of Two diiferent base_url?

Tags: drupal

Any solution to use two different `$base_url`'s for drupal 7. What i need to do is when i log to my site using `IP/VPN`, 
`$base_url` should be `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx` and 
without any vpn connections `$base_url` should be `aaaa.aaaa.aaaa.aaa`. 
Any solutions? I'm Using Drupal 7.54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without really knowing why would you need this, a possible solution could be to implement [hook_boot](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7.x) and override `$base_url` to suit your needs like this:

```
function mymodule_boot() {
    if ($condition_is_met) {
        global $base_url;
        $base_url = $new_base_url_value;
    }
}
```

Your condition could be to check client IP.

Comment: i just edit the settings fie and according to the logging ip i changed the based url.